# Testing to see if entered input is a number (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, input, syntax, nan, equality

(inputField was defined earlier as the html inputfield)

No matter what input I enter in the inputField, it will always alert 'good job!'. The code worked perfectly earlier, but I changed like one line and now I can't figure out how to fix it. Triple equality signs === don't work either.

let input = inputField.value;
var amount = parseInt(input);

```
if(amount == NaN || amount == undefined){
    alert('enter a valid number!');
}    else{
    alert('good job!');
}
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

Try trpeof to get the type of the amount.

```
console.log(typeof(amount))
```

Or to get a boolean value just use isNan.

```
console.log(isNaN(amount))
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if amount is a number or not use `isNaN(amount)`